# Excel Macro to concatenate cells and shift over

Tags: vba, excel

I want to be able to select any number of cells (all on the same row), and run a macro that will concatenate all the highlighted cells, then shift all of the remaining cells over.

My description might not be clear - hopefully this makes more sense:

In the example below, I have data in columns 1 to 8.
I would highlight the cells in colums 1 to 3, run the macro, and have the values in the highlighted cells merged to the left (with spaces between), and have the remaining cells shifted over.

**BEFORE**

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6 Column7 Column8
A       B       C       D       E       F       G       H
```

**AFTER**

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6 Column7 Column8
A B C   D       E       F       G       H
```

Is this possible to do with a macro (that I'd execute via keyboard shortcut)? I've got a general understanding of excel and vba macros, but I'm sadly not good enough to know if this is practical or possible.

I've found some macros that concatenate cells data, but not based on highlighted cells.  Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub bigmac()
    Dim r As Range, rDel As Range
    Set r = Selection
    Dim N As Long
    N = r.Count
    Set rn = r(N)
    st = ""
    For i = 1 To N
        st = st & r(i).Value
    Next i
    r(1) = st
    Set rDel = Range(r(2), r(N))
    rDel.Delete shift:=xlToLeft
End Sub
```

Comment: Keep your edit, but replace **r(1)=st** with **r(1)=Trim(st)**.

Answer (score 2):

this would definitely be possible. the execution depends on how you want to "Hgihlight" cells. if you are selecting them, you'd just use `.selection` in your code.

this is a function I use to combine columns:

```
Function combineColumns(ByVal Columns As Variant, ByVal EmptyCol As Long) As String

    Dim tempColumn As Long
    Dim str As String
    Dim base As Long

    base = LBound(Columns) 'Columns could be 0 or 1 based array


    str = "="
    'compiles string formula for combining the columns
    For i = base To UBound(Columns)
        'tempColumn = Range(Columns(i) & "1").column
        If i > base Then 'if i > base it means that the loop is not on the first run, so the "&" is added for concatenation
            str = str & "&"" ""&RC[-" & (EmptyCol - Columns(i)) & "]"
        Else
            str = str & "RC[-" & (EmptyCol - Columns(i)) & "]"
        End If

    Next

    combineColumns = str


End Function
```

That function takes an array of column numbers, and returns a string that can be inserted into a cell to combine the passed columns into the passed blank column. Should be easily adaptable to fit your solution. (loop through columns in `.selection` and add all column numbers to an array, then pass to my function, and use the returned string. )

if you are highlighting with color, you'd use a loop to go over every cell in the row and test the color. so like

```
For Each cell In activeCell.entireRow.Cells
    if cell.interior.color = RGB() then 'insert rgb for highlighting color here
        'add to array
    end if
next
```

and then you'd pass the resulting array. and then after you combine the cells, use `.delete xlShiftToLeft` which will delete the cells and shift the remaining on the row to the left to fill in the blanks. (be sure to not have the cell with the combined data selected at that point.

### edit

NOTE: the string returned by the function must be inserted into a cell ( `Cells(rownum, colnum).formulaR1C1 =` ) because if you try to use it outside of code you'll get an error